# Generating functions of a sum

Tags: generating-functions, poisson-distribution

Let $M$ be a Poisson distributed random variable with mean 4, and let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be independent identically distributed copies of a Bernoulli random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{3}{4}=1-\mathbb{P}(X=0)$.
What is the Generating function $\mathbb{E}\{z^{S}\}$ of $S=2\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{i}$.

So I know that using the property of independence I may apply that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{z^{2\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{i}}\}=\mathbb{E}\{z^{2X_{1}}\}\mathbb{E}\{z^{2X_{2}}\}\cdot\cdot\cdot\mathbb{E}\{z^{2X_{M}}\}
\end{equation}
What I do not understand is how the $M$ Poisson distributed random variable works here in combination with the Bernoulli random variable. Could someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have  to assume that $M$ is independent of $(X_i)$.

$Ez^{2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}X_i} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Ez^{2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i} e^{-4}\frac {4^{n}} {n!}$. Since $Ez^{2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i}=(Ez^{2X_1})^{n}=(\frac 1 4 +\frac 3  4z^{2})^{n}$ we get $Ez^{2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}X_i}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-4}\frac {4^{n}} {n!} (\frac 1 4 +\frac 3  4z^{2})^{n}$. The  sum of this series is  $e^{-4} e^{1+3z^{2}}$.

Comment: How did you compute the sum of the series?

Comment: It is of the form $\sum \frac {t^{n}} {n!}$ which is the series for $e^{t}$.  ($t=4(\frac  1 4+\frac   3  4z^{2})$). @TKetelaar